# What's the best language to code background tasks on Windows?

Tags: windows, background-task, multiple-languages

An exemple would be syncing through FTP a folder on my computer and on my server (I know tools exist for that but i want to try and do it myself :) ).

I'd like my "apps" to be fairly lightweight so it won't affect my computer's speed.

Thank in advance,

Answer (score 0):

.NET is a good choice to make Async operations. For example, it exists a framework, Hangfire, which makes what you are looking for. It's an open-source project with amazing people working on it. Take a look:

https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire